USB to TTL (CH340G) quickly becomes unreadable
I bought a CH340G based USB to TTL converter to interact with a new embedded system I got. The output starts out fine but becomes unreadable after a few lines
MODE:SPI NAND<\r><\n>
TURN TO USB<\r><\n>
eS-<\r><\n>
NOLINK<\r><\n>
flag bypass<\r><\n>
¯ì<28><28>,„<28>dÿ<1>„Œ”¤æŽ„[...truncated...]

I found a lot of help for problems when all the output looks broken, but the first five lines of output seem fine. At least four out of five look fine. I virtually tried all combinations of typical link settings. 115200 8n1 produces the best result, the one I posted. I tried different USB controllers and different operating systems. I even desoldered and resoldered the pins b/c I think I read somewhere, that a bad GND pin can produce such results. But to no avail.
The device is a wifi router available across the world under different brand names. In Europe it is a Strong 4GRouter300M. I am trying to recreate what others accomplished using differently branded versions in other parts of the world.
The hardware is the same, but I already learned that the firmware is quite a bit different.
I pealed the heat shields off and read and compared the component numbers to make sure I have the same kind of hardware. It is a 3 pin connector and I verified ~3.3V on the TX and RX pins with a multimeter. I connected the CH340 TX to the devices RX and vice versa and I connected the GND pins as well. I made sure I jumpered the CH340 to the same voltage. The connection cables are 20cm long.
How can proceed here? I would really like to fiddle with this device.

Finding
The gibberish is different on every run, e.g.
2F 4A 14 7E 0C 04 7E 04 04 67 2D 7F 04 04 0C 54 1E 66 0C 04 1C 10 26 45 04 04 44 4E 63 1F 4D 14
0C 0C 14 4C 55 27 0F 2C 0C 1C 0C 14 34 3D 6C 0C 14 0C 04 79 14 6F 08 04 1C 08 60 04 0F 04 14 04
04 1F 0C 06 04 4C 1C 4E 14 05 09 04 04 39 4A 70 24 1D 14 45 1C 08 4B 34 7F 09 04 0C 74 0E 47 2F
04 40 0C 14 5E 0E 6C 2E 04 14 14 70 46 0C 0C 5C 00 04 14 74 4F 34 1F 04 48 04 0C 1D 42 4C 0C 2C

vs
14 08 0C 34 0C 6C 7F 04 2D 0F 39 04 34 5E 54 1C 08 63 74 15 1C 34 08 04 04 24 0F 1F 0C 0C 04 4C
23 5D 6E 29 18 04 14 64 6F 04 48 0C 0C 14 04 3D 14 0C 14 04 64 0E 3E 04 04 1C 08 6A 04 1F 2C 14
14 00 0D 14 19 4E 14 04 24 57 0E 0F 14 04 10 42 72 4D 04 7F 57 4D 65 04 14 04 0C 72 0E 67 2D 02
1C 42 78 6C 6E 0D 7C 0D 55 7E 4A 46 04 46 72 4C 6F 4A 14 10 1C 5A 1F 14 0C 0C 0C 1F 0F 04 1C 14


Well, what is this new embedded system, and how you connected the UART to it, and how do you know it uses stable enough clock source to work, or if they even use compatible IO voltages.

Are you sure the baudrate doesn't change during the boot processs?

maybe the output is binary

@Justme It's some wifi router. This router is available across the world under different brand names. In Europe it is a Strong 4GRouter300M. I have been following instructions that worked for differently branded variants. The hardware is the same, but I already learned that the firmware is quite a bit different in :-(

@Attie I am not sure about this. Maybe it does. But should then another baud rate show gibberishi nthe beginning and then readable text later on?

@user1129682 How are you sure you can even connect the CH340 module directly to some random port? Are you even sure they use the same voltage levels? Have you verifed the voltages with a multimeter, or an oscilloscope or something? A logic analyzer could help with the determinig the garbage. Also you don't even state how you connected the CH340 to modem, with 10cm or 1 meter wires, and if you have three wires, ground, TXD and RXD.

Correct - if the baudrate doesn't match, you'll get garbage.

@Attie true. I have been trying out baud rates going in steps of 100 for days and I always captured a few seconds before moving on. The 115200 yield the best result.

@Justme I updated the question

@user1129682 So you did or did not connect the ground? Only two wires, TX and RX wires?

@Justme I connected the ground pins as well. Disconnected GND does not yield any data at all

@user1129682 I can't find any problems in what you did. Either that's what the modem sends, or the CH340 module is garbage. I would not use those. Try if some other module with another chipset works better.

@Justme I read that about the CH340 a couple of times as well, but nobody ever reported problems where the first few lines are deterministically readable. That's what confused me and made me believe maybe there is something else I could try. I'll get another device next. Thank you!

It sounds like you need a logic analyser, or better, an oscilloscope... it's possible it isn't even legitimate UART frames!...

@Attie I had ChatGPT do a logic analysis. Turns out they are eliptic stream encoded bible quotes; old testimony.

Connect an oscilloscope and check that the waveform accurately reflects the data you are seeing.
If it does the UART is working.
You may discover that the port has switched to some other line discipline baud rate or signalling scheme.

Is this an investigation in the direction to determine if the device is broken? Or can I use this information to configure the CH340 somehow to compensate?

either/both.  you want to know what it's doing, this is one way to find out what the port is doing. and confirm if the UART is working.

I was hoping for something more trivial :-( Looks like TTL uses a simple non return zero signaling. I may actually be able to do that.

You're investigating hardware with unknown firmware.  maybe the port starts talking Manchester, or PWM, or 8B10B, or switches to some unexpected baud rate, or maybe it goes high impedance and all you are reading is interferance.  Connecting a logic analyser is another option, but I'd want to confirm that the voltages are still sensible first.

I got a new USB-TTL converter. I hope it is as much better as it was more expensive. The garbgae looks a little bit different now, but it's still garbage. It really looks as if the port stops speaking UART. None of the differently branded variants of this device do that :-(
